# Algorithm for finding all paths in a NxN grid in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I have a grid NxN :

```
2  1  
4  8
```

I would like to find all paths in this grid :

```
{2,1}  
{2,1,8}  
{2,1,8,4}  
{1,8,4}
{1,8}
{8,4}
...
```

My grid is defined like this :

```
gridArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"1", nil],  
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"8", nil],nil];
```

I have an object Piece (a digit):

```
@interface Piece : NSObject {
int numCol;
int numRow;
NSNumber * value;

int nbNeighborsPieces;      

NSMutableArray *neighborsArray; 
}
```

I was able to calculate all the neighbors pieces for one piece.

But now, I would like to calculate all the path for one given piece. Then for every pieces. Using an object Path :

```
@interface Path : NSObject {

NSMutableArray * arrayOfPiece;
int sum;
}
```

kind of :

```
for(Piece * pieces in pieceArray) {
[self path:piece];
}
```

I suppose I have to use a recursive method, but I don't know how.

Comment: Your example makes clear what a path is for a 2x2 grid, but it's not so clear what to do with NxN.  Is a path always on the perimeter of a matrix?  Also, how about anti-clockwise paths?

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm to solve this problem would be very slow; I would think some where in the range of O(n^n).

You could find all paths by using something similar to a [Depth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

First I think you should change your storage approach. Instead of storing items in arrays of arrays, create a node class based upon the concept of a [Vertex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_%28graph_theory%29). This node class will represent one of the elements in your deepest arrays. Each node should have an array which will contain other nodes which are neighbours of the node. It should also have an `id` type for the object you want to store. This will allow you to create a [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). It will also allow you to more easily implement recursion.

```
@interface Node : NSObject
{
    id object;
    NSMutableArray * neighbours;
}
```

In terms of an algorithm this is what I would start with, I am sure there are modifications that can make it faster.

First create an array to hold the paths and an array to represent a path.

```
NSMutableArray *paths;
NSMutableArray *currentPath;
```

In the Node class add the method that will preform the recursion

```
- (void)findAllPathsExtending:(NSMutableArray *)path filling:(NSMutableArray *)paths 
{
    if ( [path containsObject:self] )
    {
        return;
    }

    [path addObject:self];
    [paths addObject:[path copy]];

    for (Node *aNode in neighbours)
    {
        [aNode findAllPathsExtending:path filling:paths];
    }

    [path removeObject:self];

    return; 
}
```

But this alone will not give you all paths. You will still need to preform this algorithm for every node in the graph. As I mentioned before this task becomes VERY expensive VERY quickly as you increase the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of Dijkstra algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm, or [A* search algo http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) . They are both pathFinders. Generaly Dijkstra is a little slower (more computation) but easier to implement. Dijkstra is recursive, not sure about A* search, since i never implemented one. If you have small grid, Dijkstra will really fit what you need. And will compute not only your path, but all the others. I really like it.